# Request.QueryString foi detectado no cliente Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou com problema quando o usuário confirma um email pelo cadastro padrão do Asp. O usuário recebe um link em formato html e clica no link e o usuário obtém um erro do servidor do aplicativo.

Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/meuaplicativo'.
Um valor possivelmente perigoso Request.QueryString foi detectado no cliente

Já configurei o webconfig da forma abaixo e sem sucesso. Já tenho dias trabalhando nisso e não resolvo. Podem ajudar?

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime  requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false"></pages>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Tem 1 exemplo da querystring e da forma como você recupera ela no controller?

Comment: A querysrting é uma string padrão de envio de email para confirmação do e-mail do usuário pelo entity do asp. não tenho mais a string, contornei a situação mudando o corpo do e-mail para aceitar html e mudei o código.